# How does Python manage the tie between a number symbol, and an "int" behind the scenes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Some disclaimer-type prelude; much of this question was taken on a challenge to "is it possible to do this", moreso than *IF* it's a good idea to do this in real production code - as a way to expand my understandings.

What I wanted to do is to subtype `int` such that whenever the "value" of the type was accessed it printed a log statement to the console.

if you do something like `dir(4)` you get a list of overrideable functions coming from `int`. `4` itself is caught as being of type `int`. I thought that perhaps by finding the right overrideable function that the subtype could be like:

```
class subInt(int):
  def __new__(cls, value):
    return int.__new__(cls, value)
  
  def __someFunc__():
    print('accessing')
    return int.__someFunc__()
```

My immediate question is how to pull this off, but the bigger picture question is how does Python *(Python3 if it matters)* manage the tie between the symbol `4` and the `int 4` behind the scenes?

Comment: The symbol only exists when perfoming input or output of values, it's processed by the parser, just like the `[]` around lists. Once the program has been parsed, everything is just raw data, there are no symbols.

Comment: I don't think there are any customizable methods used when getting the raw value of an object.